# If pattern matched delete newline character in that line

Tags: awk, sed, grep, tr

Let say pattern is string "Love"

input

```
This is some text
Love this or that
He is running like a rabbit
```

output

```
This is some text
Love this or thatHe is running like a rabbit
```

I've noticed that sed is very unpleasant for deleting newline characters, any idea?

Comment: `sed` works on one line at a time. Every time it starts to work on a line it removes the new line and places it on pattern space. Pattern space is where all the action takes place. Once the substitution is done it places the newline and prints to `STDOUT`. To remove new line you need to use `N` which appends the next line to pattern space separated by `\n` which you can then remove with substitution.

Comment: Do you like space between `that` and `He`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sed '/^Love/{N;s/\n//;}' love.txt
```

details:

`/^Love/` identifies the line to treat, if you like you can use `/[Ll]ove/` instead

`N` adds the next line to the pattern space. After this command the pattern space contains `Love this or that\nHe is running like a rabbit`

`s/\n//` replaces the newline character

Comment: only will say wow, it's easy when explained, are { } nececary for using key element N @casimir-et-hippolyte

Comment: @josifoski: curly brackets enclose actions to do when the condition `/^Love/` is true.

Comment: Note that after the first match and replacement, pattern space won't contain a newline before the next line that was pulled in due to the N, and therefore if you had a different pattern to match at the beginning of the next line, it won't be matched. E.g. consider what happens with input file "Love\nLove\nLove". The second Love never gets matched.

Comment: @SomeGuy: `sed ':a;/[Ll]ove[^\n]*$/{N;ba};s/\n//g' love.txt` solves the problem with a simple loop to append each consecutive matching line before the replacement (global this time).

Answer (score 3):

Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(Love[^\n]*)\n/\1/' file.txt
This is some text
Love this or thatHe is running like a rabbit
```

Or, if the intent is solely focused on the `\n` you can `chomp` based on a pattern:

```
$ perl -pe 'chomp if /^Love/' file.txt
This is some text
Love this or thatHe is running like a rabbit
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/Love/{printf "%s ",$0;next} 1' file
This is some text
Love this or that He is running like a rabbit
```

Explanation:

- `/Love/{printf "%s ",$0;next}`

  For lines that contain `Love`, the line is printed, via `printf`, without a newline.  `awk` then starts over on the `next` line.
- `1`

  For lines that don't include `Love`, they are printed normally (with a newline).  The `1` command is awk's cryptic shorthand for print normally.

Comment: thank you for solution, in some future will take some time to learn awk. For now am on sed mostly

Answer (score 2):

Through Perl,

```
$ perl -pe 's/^Love.*\K\n//' file
This is some text
Love this or thatHe is running like a rabbit
```

`\K` discards previously matched characters.

**OR**

```
$ perl -pe '/^Love/ && s/\n//' file
This is some text
Love this or thatHe is running like a rabbit
```

If a line starts with the string `Love`, then it removes the newline character from that line.

Comment: Use `chomp` if just the newline needs to be removed. `perl -pe 'chomp if /^Love/' file`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk`variation:

```
awk '{ORS=(/Love/?FS:RS)}1' file
This is some text
Love this or that He is running like a rabbi
```

This change the `ORS` based on the pattern

---

Here are some other `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(/Love/?FS:RS)}' file
This is some text
Love this or that He is running like a rabbit
```

If line has  `Love` in it use `FS` as separator, else use `RS`

This should work too, but use the first one.

```
awk '{printf "%s"(/Love/?FS:RS),$0}' file
```

Comment: If you do not like the space between the two lines, use `awk '{ORS=(/Love/?"":RS)}1'`  Even this can be used: `awk 'ORS=(/Love/?FS:RS)'`